# Extend or get rid of sidebar jobs ad tooltip

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising, tooltips

I just noticed the new design of the sidebar Jobs/Careers advertisement, and as I always do, hovered. The tooltip was... less than useful:

> [image]

"Full" what? Why? What value does it add?

Can this either be removed (better option, can't see any need for tooltip at all) or at least be extended to show more useful information?

Comment: The *"Full"* seems to be the first word of the job title (*Full Stack Developer*). For me it says *"Software"* when hovering an ad for *Software Engineer Android*. Guess it's a bug.

Comment: @Floern thanks, but still, can't see any reason to have the title of the job as tooltip, it got enough visibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title accidentally wasn't getting quoted, so the browser was just using the first word. But I agree with you that the title is not useful. The job title and company name are right there on the ad and the hover text is more likely to block text that you're trying to read than to be helpful. So I've removed it, and it's live now. Thank you.

Comment: Not quoting a HTML attribute can lead to XSS when the value of that attribute is provided by user.

Comment: @Gothdo yes, not properly quoting or escaping user input is a whole class of security vulnerabilities we're all aware of. Although, I will point out that our clients, who pay us hundreds or thousands of dollars to run job listings, don't use their job listing titles to try to exploit security vulnerabilities. So, while there was a risk, the _real world_ risk was low. And, again, it's gone now.